# Eclipse console hyperlink only can jump to Java class file in referenced libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, console, log4j2

I need create  hyperlink in eclipse console to link File name on the console to java source file. However, Eclipse only can jump to Java class file in the "referenced libraries" but cannot jump to Java source files.
My project is a Maven project. Any idea to make Eclipse console search files in source code folder instead of only search on the "referenced libraries" ?
My Eclipse is Spring IDE 3.8.4 which is based on the Eclipse Neon.3.

**Below figure is OK case, FrameworkServlet.java:489 is a class in referenced libraries.** 
[image]

***However if file is a Java source file in src/main/java then Eclipse cannot jump to that file* (FileUtils.java)**

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to ensure that your source folder is on the build path. Go to your project properties, click Java Build Path in the left pane, click the Source tab in the right pane. If your source folder is not present, add it. Eclipse should be able to find your source file after you do this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it still cannot jump. My Java Build Path already included directory "src/main/java".

Comment: My problem is Eclipse only looks for java source files at "referenced libraries" but not looking for java files at "src/main/java". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what D.B. mentioned, make sure the source folders is high in the Order and Export tab so that Eclipse would look for current project's source class first.